# Yii minimum necessary code for filtering to work in gridview

Tags: gridview, yii, filter

What is the bare, most necessary, minimum code for ajax filtering to work in gridview?

In:

- controller,
- model,
- view

because I don't know why, but filtering stopped working while I was messing with other things. I can see ajax loading but results are always the same, it doesn't filter data. In firebug, I can see the GET call, but I don't really know what happens, or what query is coming back, or how to check what query is running in background.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on this [Yii wiki article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/381/cgridview-clistview-and-cactivedataprovider) **thanks to softark** it is very easy to understand what happens when users are filtering in grid. also, if you set

> 'ajaxUpdate' => false,

you can see what is happening in the background, and using firebug or CWebLogRoute you can see if there are any errors with the query or variables. for example I had this error (warning) message:

> Failed to set unsafe attribute ...